# JavaScript: Passing parameters to a callback function in "then" section

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass some parameter to a function used as callback, in "then" section. How can I do that?

In the following example, ***executionContext*** results as "undefined" in the callaback function.

```
function page_refresh(executionContext)
{
    Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog({ text: "Now I'll refresh page"}).then(
        function (success) {
            var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
            formContext.data.refresh(true);
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: That would mean that it's `undefined` in `page_refresh()` too. How is that function called?

Comment: when page_refresh is called, executionContext has a value, but if I try to use it in function(success) it results "undefined"

Comment: That would only be true if `page_refresh()` explicitly sets it to `undefined`.  You can place a `console.log(executionContext)` to verify. Also, it would be helpful if you would post the **exact** error message that you're getting.